# Python double loop for

Tags: python, python-3.x

`X = [[0 for i in range(6)] for j in range(6)]`
I'm used to simple for loops like: `for i in range(5)`:
but i couldn't understand this code! what's the meaning of the "0" at the beginning?

my code:

```
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
```

but what should i  put inside the loop?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it to see what it generates?

Comment: Examine `X` after executing the statement. It should be obvious that the list comprehension builds a list containing six lists of six zeros each. Just make your code do the same. You don't even need a nested for-loop to do this.

Comment: yall I dont think he understands list comprehensions yet

Comment: Running the code, see what happens and trying to figure it out from there should be the first step. And I say it not as a way of censoring learning questions, which are great, but because is the most efficient way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

this is a list comprehension, its basically the same as saying :

```
X = []
for i in range(6):
    sublist=[]
    for j in range(6)
        sublist.append(0)
    X.append(sublist)
```

so you end with a nested list filled with 0s in the end, but the list comprehension is much more compact and faster in certain cases

Answer (score 0):

This is called `List Comprehension`

```
X = [[0 for i in range(6)] for j in range(6)]
```

here for each index of `j`, a list should be generated by `[0 for i in range(6)]`
here, `[0 for i in range(6)]`, for each index of `i`, `0` is being added to the list and generating a list something like this `[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]`. This list will be generated 6 times, since `j` iterate from 0-5 (6 times).
So, the output should be `[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]`